# Azure Worker Role configuration issue while using SlowCheetah with custom config

Tags: configuration, azure, nlog, azure-worker-roles, slowcheetah

We are using Nlog as logging tool with our Worker Role of Azure app. 
It requires NLog.config file. We installed "SlowCheetah - XML Transforms", and have two Debug/Release transforms).

Solution does get rebuild successfully.

But when I try to run, I am getting following error. (I used exact transformation for nolog.config in one of my Windows service app, and it is working fine there).

> Error 163 The item "bin\Debug\NLog.config" in item list "OutputGroups"
>   does not define a value for metadata "TargetPath".  In order to use
>   this metadata, either qualify it by specifying
>   %(OutputGroups.TargetPath), or ensure that all items in this list
>   define a value for this metadata. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure
>   Tools\1.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  2299    5   Insight.CloudWeb

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is done by the SlowCheetah extension, but could you verify if your *.csproj file contains the AfterCompile target similar to this?

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
  AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />

<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="exists(’app.$(Configuration).config’)">
  <TransformXml Source="NLog.config"
    Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config"
    Transform="NLog.$(Configuration).config" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="NLog.config"/>
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
      <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
    </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Take a look at Oleg's blog post [.Config File Transformation](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/12/config-file-transformation/) under **App.config File Transformation** for more information.

Comment: I think your suggestion will only work if I remove slowcheetah completely. I will try that once I get no help to get it work using SlowCheetah add-on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix for this. Now you should be able to transform app.config as well as other XML files for Azure Worker Roles using SlowCheetah. Once I get the fix verified I will release the update to the VS gallery.

If you would like to try the fix you can download the updated VSIX at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40134810/SlowCheetah/issue-44/SlowCheetah-issue-44.zip. If you are interested in following up on this please use the [issue #44](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/44).